# How much force can connective tissue withstand?

Tags: human-anatomy, anatomy

I have been studying a 3D anatomy model. Based on visual observation,  it doesn't look like the bones would be able to stabilize themselves at all without the connective tissue like ligaments. In the model I have been studying, i've noticed that all the ligaments are clustered around joints or areas where the bones connect and it looks like it they act as a kind of glue to in essence keep the joints intact. However, I don't really understand how much force connected tissue must withstand on a regular basis.

How hard is it to keep bones aligned and confined enough that the bodies overall shape remains pretty constant? Is this the role of connective tissue? if so, how much force does such tissue need to withstand on a regular basis?

Comment: Do you have a specific connective tissue in mind? I'm guessing you are thinking of cartilage and ligament (blood is technically a connective tissue). Also in what orientation are the loads you are thinking of? Compression is very different from tension.

Comment: Ligaments and cartilage. Isn't that all there is? Is blood actually a significant player as a connective tissue?